# Mail client supporting GMail's inbox tabs/categories?

Tags: email-client

Is there a mail client supporting GMail's inbox tabs/categories like Primary/Updates/Promotions, showing you a separate view of just your Primary inbox?

I'd personally like this for Mac.

Comment: "I'd personally like this for Mac." - then add the appropriate tag. must it be free, or (how much) are you willing to pay?

Comment: I'd like to know if there are any; I might pay. I thought I'd make the question general to help non-Mac users searching for it - is the norm/rule here to make the tags and description maximally specific for your *personal* use case?

Comment: A good question. Unless @Izzy disagrees, I would say, yes, please ask for your own personal case. Otherwise, we just end up with "what's the best xxx?, which we don't really want. "What's the best xxx for these requirements?" is strongly preferable. And the more specific that you can make it, the more likely that we can give you something appropriate.